# Android: Black screen flashes when activity resumes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am having an issue with a `TabbedActivity` I have created.

I notice if I put my application in the background and then bring it back to the foreground, the screen goes black for a moment before the layout reappears. It looks as if the activity is being recreated, but I have confirmed that `onCreate()` is NOT being called when the app is resumed.

I set breakpoints in the `onResume()` and `onStart()` methods in the activity to see when the black screen occurs. When the app comes back to the foreground, `onStart()` is called, then `onResume()`, and THEN the screen flashes black for a split second. After this, the layout reappears. This is shown here:

[image: black screen flash]

I would like to note that this activity's `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods are empty besides the calls to their superclasses. The fragment that is shown in the above gif doesn't even override the `onResume()` or `onCreate()` methods. Also, in other activities in my app that are NOT tabbed activities, this behavior does not occur - it only occurs in the `TabbedActivity`.

Please let me know if more information is needed and I will gladly provide it. I'm just not exactly sure where this problem could possibly be occurring.

**EDIT**:
I've realized when I comment out the contents of ANOTHER FRAGMENT'S `onResume()` method, this no longer occurs. Here is what that method looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("RESUME");
        
        if (mShowCamera != null)
        {
            mShowCamera.camera = null;
        }
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mShowCamera = new ShowCamera(getContext(), mCamera);
        mMainCamLayout = (FrameLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.camLayout);
        mMainCamLayout.addView(mShowCamera);
        Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
        if (cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes() != null &&
                cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
        {
            mCamera.setParameters(cameraParameters);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. The issue was that there was a lot of work being done when my application came back into focus. This caused the time required to load the activity to increase.

This activity has a few fragments attached to it. One contributing factor to this problem was trying to cache too many fragments like so:

```
ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Minimizing the number of off-screen pages made the initial loading of my activity noticeably faster.

If your activity is taking a long time to load, try reducing the amount of work it has to do in its OnCreate and OnResume methods.